# Can't submit transactions to node independent of ACL settings

Tags: node, transactions, public-node

I've set up two nodes - one for mainnet and one for testnet (currently Hangzhounet).
Despite the nodes being up and healthy, and bootstrapped -- verified by ...

```
tezos-client -E https://mainnet.<my-node>.com bootstrapped
Warning:

Node is bootstrapped.
```

-- I am unable to send transactions. In temple I'm able to add the node but see

```
Invalid request provided or RPC node is temporarily unreachable.
```

Using [Better Call Dev](https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1HDXjPtjv7Y7XtJxrNc5rNjnegTi2ZzNfv/interact?entrypoint=claim) I am testing out a contract call on [Kolibri to claim DAO tokens](https://kolibri.finance/farming).

Submitting with my node on both my mainnet node (with an ACL) and testnet node (`--allow-all-rpc` set) I get the following error:

```
Rpc request failed:
   - meth: POST
   - uri: https://<my-node>/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/simulate_operation
   - error: The server doesn't authorize this endpoint (ACL filtering).
```

Here is [a link to the ACL I'm using](https://gist.github.com/decentralgabe/4a9b7a7c00e9653ed43fe436e9ac7521) on my mainnet node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your nodes with `--rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732` parameters or modify your config to allow remote access by adding 0.0.0.0 to `rpc.listen-addrs` :

```
{
  "rpc": {
    "listen-addrs": [
      "0.0.0.0:8732"
    ],
    "cors-origin": [
      "*"
    ],
    "cors-headers": [
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range, GET, POST"
    ],
    "acl": [
      {
        "address": "0.0.0.0:8732",
        "whitelist": [
           ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. I had tried to add the ipv6 version to the acl which didn't work properly - there might be a bug there. specifying ipv4 for this is fine as I can handle both types of IPs at a higher layer.